# Struggling with jQuery delay popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I'm hoping for a little assistance with an issue I'm having.

I have a popup on my site `newsletter-popup-conatiner`. (yes, that is the actual misspell of container used throughout the site)

From what I understand, the following 'should' delay the popup by 5 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#newsletter-popup-conatiner).show();
},5000);
```

Here is the newsletter module. After several unsuccessful attempts, I'm at a loss where to actually put the delay code.

```
$("#newsletter-popup-conatiner").mouseup(function(e){
        var popContainer = $("#newsletter-popup-conatiner");
        var newsLatterPop = $("#newsletter-pop-up"); 
        if(e.target.id != newsLatterPop.attr('id') && !newsLatterPop.has(e.target).length)
    {
      popContainer.fadeOut();
    }        
  });

  $('.hide-popup').on("click", function(){
    var popContainer = $("#newsletter-popup-conatiner");
    $('#newsletter-popup-conatiner')
    {
      popContainer.fadeOut();
    }
  });

  $('#dont_show').on("click", function(){
    $.cookie('popup_cookie', 'pclosed', {
      expires: 3,
      path: '/'
    });
    $('.hide-popup').trigger('click');
  });
  // console.log($.cookie('popup_cookie'));

  {% if settings.show_pupup and template == 'index'%}
  if($.cookie('popup_cookie') == 'pclosed') {
    $('.hide-popup').trigger('click');
  }
  {% endif %}

});
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the problem? What do you want? And How it is currently behaving?

Comment: do you see any errors in console. because you have a missed a quotes `$('#newsletter-popup-conatiner).show();` here.

Comment: Hi there Kenny, thanks for the reply. The problem is that i can't get the delay to work (using the code posted above) on the popup. I would like some guidance as to where i'm going wrong, as mentioned above. Its current behavior is that it pops up immediately after the site loads. THank you

Comment: Hi Don'tDownVote, sorry, that was a copy/paste error. The missing quote is present in the site. There are no errors in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#newsletter-popup-conatiner').show(); 
  }, 5000);
}
</script>
</body>
```

You can try this. It will show your container after 5 seconds on loading the page.

Comment: Hi there Varun,
Thank you for the reply.
That is working to delay the form, however it's still also showing up on page load instantly aswell

Comment: I'll have a look to see where it's being activated on page load instantly and remove that code. Thank you again for the solution provided.